# Can not play some flv videos in exoplayer android

Tags: android, flv, exoplayer, playing

I m creating a player using exoplayer. In forums it says that flv videos are supported. I can play some videos, and videoses with resolution 640x360. But i cant play videos of 1280x720 resolution and other resolution.
pls help. thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure the FLV contains H.264 video with either AAC or MP3 audio. FLV can contain other codecs like VP6 or Sorenson or JPEG etc so they might not all be supported by the Exoplayer. So having the FLV with MPEG audio/video is your best approach.

Answer (score -1):

exoplayer not work correctly with flv. few days ago I found this fix, but I have not proved myself yet.

[github info , flv not work](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/860)

[fix](https://github.com/KMK-ONLINE/ExoPlayer/commit/82fd57c94acaf7031ce4e59aae02464d7dffcb12)

Comment: "exoplayer not work correctly with flv..." but FLV is in the source code. I think seeking within an FLV is the problem. Its not impossible to fix but **[the FLV code](https://github.com/KMK-ONLINE/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/extractor/flv/FlvExtractor.java)** needs extra editing...

Comment: All your urls are broken